# Javascript mouseover Element Flickers & Uncaught TypeError

Tags: javascript, html, dom, addeventlistener

I am trying to use javaScript mouseover and mousout function to get elements from the DOM. sourced child elements from that event.target and add styling to the childNode that matches the specified class name.

Issue that are occurring:

Error: **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined**

Displayed class flickers. when mouse is moved even with in the mouse Over current DOM element.

I've tried to get elements by tag name and childNodes filtered through for statemant to apply css, but still issue's

Its probably an easy fix but am baffled.

Any assistance would be great.

**The HTML**

```
<!doctype HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Gmail Label List</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="func.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="sideBar-left">
        <div class="SbInner-body">
            <ul id="label-list">
                <li class="lb_li">
                    <div class="lb-title">Label List 1</div>
                    <div class="lb-a-icon">
                        <img src="chevron_expand.png">
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="lb_li">
                    <div class="lb-title">Label List 1</div>
                    <div class="lb-a-icon">
                        <img src="chevron_expand.png">
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="lb_li">
                    <div class="lb-title">Label List 1</div>
                    <div class="lb-a-icon">
                        <img src="chevron_expand.png">
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="lb_li">
                    <div class="lb-title">Label List 1</div>
                    <div class="lb-a-icon">
                        <img src="chevron_expand.png">
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**THE CSS**

```
body

{
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
}

div#sideBar-left{
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    width:180px;
}

div.SbInner-body{}
 ul#label-list{
    background-color: #898989;
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
ul#label-list li {
    list-style: none;
    cursor:pointer;
    background-color: #989898;
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
div.lb-title{
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    height:auto;
    width:auto;
    padding:5px;
}

div.lb-a-icon{
    position:relative;
    float:right;
    height:15px;
    padding:10px;
    width:16px;
    border:1px solid black;
    display: none;
}
```

**THE JS**

```
function showLabel_icon(element)
{
        element.target.getElementsByClassName('lb-a-icon')[0].style.display="block";
}

function closeLabel_icon(element)
{
        element.target.getElementsByClassName('lb-a-icon')[0].style.display="none";
}

//[ Listeners]
function Add_DOM_listeners(){
    if(window.addEventListener){
        var lb = document.getElementById('label-list')
        var lb_child = lb.getElementsByClassName('lb_li');
        for(var i = 0; i < lb_child.length; i++){
            lb_child[i].addEventListener('mouseover',showLabel_icon, false);
        }// end for


        var lc = document.getElementById('label-list')
        var lc_child = lc.getElementsByClassName('lb_li');
        for(var j = 0; j < lc_child.length; j++){
            lc_child[j].addEventListener('mouseout',closeLabel_icon, false);
        }// end for

    }// end if 
}//end function



window.onload = function(){
    Add_DOM_listeners();
}
```

Comment: `.lb_li:hover .lb-a-icon { display: block; }` doesn't work? http://jsfiddle.net/CHTKM/

Comment: I think the event.target should be event.currentTarget

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Suggested solution

I think that, unless there's other logic not described in the question, the entire JavaScript section can be replaced by the following CSS declaration:

```
/* By default the icon is not rendered: */
.lb-a-icon {
    display: none;
}
/* When <li> is hovered, its icon child is displayed: */
.lb_li:hover .lb-a-icon {
    display: block;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/CHTKM/

You can also play around with `visibility: hidden;` and `visibility: visible;`

### Reason of TypeError

The `event.target` references an element the cursor is pointing to. Suppose you add the event listener to your `<li>` that has the following HTML structure...

```
<li class="lb_li">
    <div class="lb-title">Label List 1</div>
    <div class="lb-a-icon">
        <img src="chevron_expand.png">
    </div>
</li>
```

Now when you hover the mouse over `<li>` contents, the `event.target` could point, for example, to `<div class="lb-title">Label List 1</div>` which doesn't have any elements with `lb-a-icon` class. Attempting to get those non-existing elements results in `undefined` which, obviously, has no `style` property and thus an error is thrown.

To solve the issue you can use `this` (but not in IE6-8!), which references the element to which the event listener is added.

```
function showLabel_icon() {
    // In this particular case "this" is <li class="lb_li">
    this.getElementsByClassName('lb-a-icon')[0].style.display = 'block';
}
```

### JavaScript advice

If you want to stick with JavaScript, instead of:

```
window.onload = function () {
    Add_DOM_listeners();
}
```

It's much better to write:

```
window.addEventListener('load', add_DOM_listeners);
```

Doing it this way, you won't have the overhead of creating an additional function. You will also avoid inadvertently overriding any other `onload` listener present on your page.

Also, your `Add_DOM_listeners` function can be reduced to the following:

```
function Add_DOM_listeners() {
    var labelList = document.getElementById('label-list'),
        labelChildren = labelList.getElementsByClassName('lb_li'),
        ii = labelChildren.length,
        i;

    for (i = 0; i < ii; i += 1) {
        labelChildren[i].addEventListener('mouseover', showLabel_icon);
        labelChildren[i].addEventListener('mouseout', closeLabel_icon);
    }
}
```

### Compatibility

For IE6-8, of course, you'll need `attachEvent` and `window.event.srcElement`.

Comment: Thanks Oleg this explains a lot. Regarding your question about using javascript over css for this: I was going to animate the icon via opacity once i got passed this issue.

Comment: I'll have to look into this. Question- Is there any advantages of using javascript over css for these kinds of simple animations?

Comment: @GarveySnow Using CSS for animations will result in a better performance. Check animation guidelines on the bottom of the following page: http://paulirish.com/2012/why-moving-elements-with-translate-is-better-than-posabs-topleft/